# When reviewing a Reopen, are you supposed to review an edit, or the question itself?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

I was reviewing edits for a Reopen queue. One of them was, in my opinion, pretty straightforward - a question was put on hold as Off-topic, and the edit I was reviewing was a simple grammar/formatting correction. Thing like that would definitely not qualify an off-topic question to be reopened.

Except, if I clicked "Leave Closed" I would have failed an audit - the question was a well upvoted one and was never closed. The question I was reviewing was about the technology I'm not using myself, and I usually skip those - except blatantly obvious reviews like that (grammar/formatting edits in off-topic question).

What's the official interpretation here? When reviewing Reopen votes, are we supposed to review just the Edit itself, or entire question plus the edit? If it is just the edit, then it may lead to a failed audit.

Comment: Review the final question itself, not the edit which is applied. When the correct action is not obvious you are correct in skipping it.

Comment: Good question. The way I see it, the goal of that queue is not to review edits but to review if questions need to be reopened or not. An edit is simply a trigger that puts a question into the queue and acts as additional information to guide you to a choice.

Comment: Also happened to me once. It's somewhat devious to use questions in reopen audits that were never closed. We are rather tested whether we consider a question to be closed than to reopen it on the basis of the editing history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Review the question, not just the edit.**

From the [FAQ - Guidelines for reviewing Reopen Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450):

> **Don't** just review the edit, if an edit is shown.
>
> If the post is edited after being closed, the system might show you just the edits that took place after closure, rather than the whole post itself. Sometimes these edits might just be minor, not affecting the acceptability of the question but simply making grammar or formatting fixes. **Don't just review them as "Leave Closed" just because the edit is minor**; it might be possible that the closure wasn't warranted in the first place, or that the post can be edited to be reopenable. Be sure to evaluate the question itself, not just the edit.