# Should I vote for reopen if the only change is the removal of "thanks"?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

About [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23952120) in the Reopen review queue, which was triggered [by an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57568766/revisions), I failed the audit by answering "leave closed".

Actually, now that I looked at the question, I can see no problem with it and I would vote to reopen it.

But my rationale, when I just see the edits in the queue, was "is the edit is a reason to amend the conclusion of other reviewers"? In this case, for me the edit in itself is not a good reason to change the status of the question.

Usually, my "workflow" for review on the Reopen queue is :

- If the edit is a minor one (grammar fix, format fix, removal of politeness phrases),
- then *don't* nominate for reopen

Am I wrong in my interpretation of the review queue?

Comment: Audits are tricky. The usualy workflow for users is looking at what any potential edits change, but not necessarily if it was rightfully closed in the first place. Mistakes do happen, and a relevant edit that fixes any problems could be burried deeper in the history. Always look at the question, not just the edit

Comment: Shamelessly advertising my own [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387692/11682469).

Comment: @JeanneDark I would even say my question is very likely a duplicate from the one you answered

Comment: Never underestimate the power of the **skip** button.

Answer (score 8):

You should evaluate the question, not the actions taken with the question.

If you do not know enough as to make an informed decision about closing or reopening the question, you can't depend on the edit made to decide to reopen it or to leave it closed. In these cases, as usual, skipping is the recommended course of action.

A question that in your eyes deserves to be reopened (maybe you disagree with the original closure) shouldn't remain closed because the latest edit was a good one, but didn't deal with a close reason that *may not have been appropriate to begin with*.

Edits are helpful information that you can use in your analysis, but not the only data point to consider, nor the most important.

The queue is to review posts, not edits.