# Add a setting to open the question in "revised" mode, not in "revision"

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, user-experience

When performing a review in the "Reopen Votes" queue I would like to open the question in "Question (revised)" mode, but when I get the next question, the "Revision" tab is shown by default:

> [image: Reopen queue]

and there is no setting to set this as the preferred behaviour.

Can this setting be implemented, or the active tab be remembered?

Comment: There's no setting for it.

Comment: @Zoe before the edit by yivi the question asked "Can it be implemented please?". Also it is tagged "feature-request", not "support".

Comment: I guess just something as simple as put it in localStorage would do :D

Answer (score 3):

This would definitely be useful.

> [Be sure to evaluate the question itself, not just the edit.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387692/)

While being able to see what *exactly* was changed after closure is a handy option to be easily accessible, it's more important to consider whether the question *as a whole, in its current state* is worthy of reopening.

Short of an official solution, this is trivial to implement client-side. [Here's a userscript](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/raw/master/Review-Reopen-Revised-Tab/Review-Reopen-Revised-Tab.user.js) which automatically clicks the "Question (revised)" tab when a new task appears. (You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/))